# All combinations of a list of lists

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I'm basically looking for a python version of [Combination of `List<List<int>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545703/combination-of-listlistint)

Given a list of lists, I need a new list that gives all the possible combinations of items between the lists.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]] -> [[1,4,7],[1,4,8],...,[3,6,10]]
```

The number of lists is unknown, so I need something that works for all cases. Bonus points for elegance!

Answer (score 635, accepted):

you need [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*a))
[(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 4, 10), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 5, 10), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (1, 6, 10), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 4, 10), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 5, 10), (2, 6, 7), (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 4, 10), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 5, 10), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9), (3, 6, 10)]
```

Comment: Could someone explain the meaning of the asterisk in `*a`?

Comment: `*a` means these are arguments being passed to the function or method. `def fn(a,b,c):` would respond to `fn(*[1,2,3])` [reference](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)

Comment: @mjallday, would it be possible to add also these combinations: (7,4,1),(8,4,1),(9,4,1),(10,4,1),(7,5,1),(8,5,1),(9,5,1),(10,5,1) etc?

Comment: @Reman It's not entirely clear what you want to get but if it is, for example, also the reverse of each tuple you can use a a wrapper function that takes `a` as input, iterates over `itertools.product(*a)` and `yield`s both the tuple produced by `itertools` and a reverse version (e.g. create a list, `reverse()` it and convert back to tuple). Best ask a new question.

Comment: if you are familiar with javascript `[*a]` would be the same the js spread operator `[...a]`. This is also true for dicts

Answer (score 29):

Simply use `itertools.product`:

```
listOLists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
for l in itertools.product(*listOLists):
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 28):

The most elegant solution is to use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in python 2.6.

If you aren't using Python 2.6, the docs for `itertools.product` actually show an equivalent function to do the product the "manual" way:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Answer (score 16):

Nothing wrong with straight up recursion for this task, no need for external dependencies, and if you need a version that works with strings, this might fit your needs:

```
combinations = []

def combine(terms, accum):
    last = (len(terms) == 1)
    n = len(terms[0])
    for i in range(n):
        item = accum + terms[0][i]
        if last:
            combinations.append(item)
        else:
            combine(terms[1:], item)


>>> a = [['ab','cd','ef'],['12','34','56']]
>>> combine(a, '')
>>> print(combinations)
['ab12', 'ab34', 'ab56', 'cd12', 'cd34', 'cd56', 'ef12', 'ef34', 'ef56']
```

Answer (score 6):

Numpy can do it:

```
 >>> import numpy
 >>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
 >>> [list(x) for x in numpy.array(numpy.meshgrid(*a)).T.reshape(-1,len(a))]
[[ 1, 4, 7], [1, 5, 7], [1, 6, 7], ....]
```

Comment: Could someone explain this?

Comment: This does not work if the things in a are arrays. `a=[[[array A], [array B], [array C]], [...]`

Comment: this feels like asking 'how do i boil water' and instead of saying 'use a kettle', you get 'lower the atmospheric pressure around the water'. Both work!

Answer (score 5):

One can use base python for this. The code needs a function to flatten lists of lists:

```
def flatten(B):    # function needed for code below;
    A = []
    for i in B:
        if type(i) == list: A.extend(i)
        else: A.append(i)
    return A
```

Then one can run:

```
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]

outlist =[]; templist =[[]]
for sublist in L:
    outlist = templist; templist = [[]]
    for sitem in sublist:
        for oitem in outlist:
            newitem = [oitem]
            if newitem == [[]]: newitem = [sitem]
            else: newitem = [newitem[0], sitem]
            templist.append(flatten(newitem))

outlist = list(filter(lambda x: len(x)==len(L), templist))  # remove some partial lists that also creep in;
print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 4, 7], [3, 4, 7], 
[1, 5, 7], [2, 5, 7], [3, 5, 7], 
[1, 6, 7], [2, 6, 7], [3, 6, 7], 
[1, 4, 8], [2, 4, 8], [3, 4, 8], 
[1, 5, 8], [2, 5, 8], [3, 5, 8], 
[1, 6, 8], [2, 6, 8], [3, 6, 8], 
[1, 4, 9], [2, 4, 9], [3, 4, 9], 
[1, 5, 9], [2, 5, 9], [3, 5, 9], 
[1, 6, 9], [2, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], 
[1, 4, 10], [2, 4, 10], [3, 4, 10], 
[1, 5, 10], [2, 5, 10], [3, 5, 10], 
[1, 6, 10], [2, 6, 10], [3, 6, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This mostly mimics solutions like [Answer by Jarret Hardie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/798893/1357094) using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but has these distinctions:

- this passes parameters to `itertools.product` in-line, instead of via variable `a` - so no `*args` syntax needed on the inline parameters
- if your [mypy type-linter](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html) acts like mine, and you can get your code to otherwise "work" with the `*args` syntax with inline `product` parameters (like `product(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]])`), `mypy` might still fail it (with something like `error: No overload variant of "product" matches argument type "List[object]"`)
- So solution to that `mypy`, is to not use `*args` syntax, like this:

```
    >>> import itertools
    >>> list(itertools.product([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]))
    [(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 4, 10), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 5, 10), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (1, 6, 10), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 4, 10), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 5, 10), (2, 6, 7), (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 4, 10), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 5, 10), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9), (3, 6, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't as clean as using itertools but the ideas could be useful.

Drawing inspiration from the construction of zip() [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), we could do the following.

```
>>> a = iter([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]])
>>> sentinel = object()
>>> result = [[]]
>>> while True:
>>>     l = next(a,sentinel)
>>>     if l == sentinel:
>>>         break
>>>     result = [ r + [digit] for r in result for digit in l]
>>> print(result)
[[1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 10], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9], [1, 5, 10], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9], [1, 6, 10], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 4, 10], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 9], [2, 5, 10], [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8], [2, 6, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 4, 9], [3, 4, 10], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 9], [3, 5, 10], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 10]]
```

We use `a` as an iterator in order to successively get the next item of it without needing to know how many there are a priori. The `next` command will output `sentinel` (which is an object created solely to make this comparison, see [here](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/) for some explanation) when we run out of lists in `a`, causing the `if` statement to trigger so we break out of the loop.

Comment: Indeed this is more or less what `itertools.product` does, -- see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) -- except the use of a sentinel while `itertools.product` uses `yield`.

Answer (score -1):

```py
from itertools import product 
list_vals = [['Brand Acronym:CBIQ', 'Brand Acronym :KMEFIC'],['Brand Country:DXB','Brand Country:BH']]
list(product(*list_vals))
```

Output:

> [('Brand Acronym:CBIQ', 'Brand Country :DXB'),
>       ('Brand Acronym:CBIQ', 'Brand Country:BH'),
>       ('Brand Acronym :KMEFIC', 'Brand Country :DXB'),
>       ('Brand Acronym :KMEFIC', 'Brand Country:BH')]

Comment: This answer should be accepted, since it's the only one using a built-in function, while highlighting that it also works for any and also heterogenous types.

Comment: How is this answer any different than the one provided many years ago?

Comment: The types of the parameters here are homogenous, not hetrogenous.