# Find all possible combinations

Tags: python, list

I asked this question earlier but regarding another programming languages.

Let's say I have a couple roots, prefixes, and suffixes.

```
roots = ["car insurance", "auto insurance"]
prefix = ["cheap", "budget"]
suffix = ["quote", "quotes"]
```

Is there a simple function in Python which will allow me to construct all possible combinations of the three character vectors.

So I want a list or other data structures which returns the following list of all possible combinations of each string.

```
cheap car insurance quotes
cheap car insurance quotes
budget auto insurance quotes
budget insurance quotes
...
```

Comment: Duplicate of [All combinations of a list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists). And many others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+all+combinations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for p, r, s in itertools.product(prefix, roots, suffix):
    print p, r, s
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to import libraries as Python has builtin syntax for this already. Rather than just printing, it returns a data structure like you asked for, and you get to join the strings together to boot:

```
combinations = [
    p + " " + t + " " + s
    for t in ts for p in prefix for s in suffix]
```