# Unusual permutations

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I have few lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9,10]
```

How do I generate all combinations like:

```
a[0], b[0]
a[1], b[1]
a[2], b[2]
a[0], b[0], c[0]
a[1], b[1], c[0]
a[2], b[2], c[0]
a[1], b[1], c[1]
a[2], b[2], c[2]
a[0], b[0], c[3]
a[1], b[1], c[3]
a[2], b[2], c[3]
.....
```

There can be only one value at a time from each list.

Imagine two or more lists Like a=[1,2,3] and b=[4,5,6] and c=[7,8,9] and I would like all possible pairs like (a[0], b[0]),(a[1], b[1]), (a[0], b[0], c[0])...

Comment: [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), with length required. Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python?rq=1 as per side bar.

Comment: What's so unusual in this, and how is this different than all the other permutations questions on SO?

Comment: I want a* to occur only once in a list. It can't be a1, a2, a3 or b1,b2,c1

Comment: Is things like `'a1'` your real string pattern, that is, how can you specify what is `'a'` and `'*'` in your real scene?

Comment: @YiFei I've got a list like a=[1,2,3] and b=[4,5,6] and I would like all possible pairs like a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1] and so on.

Comment: You should probably use `itertools.product` for this, but it's still not clear exactly what combinations you want. Should the output contain (a[0], c[0]) or (b[0], c[0])? BTW, (a[0], b[0], c[0]) contains 3 items so it is not a pair.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes I wanted product for this. I know it's not a pair just tried to explain what I mean. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your example, you seem to want only `abc`-type permutations. So you either: 1) build your "permutations" explicitly, or 2) build all permutations and filter out those you do not want.

**Explicit construction**

1. Build your `list_of_lists`, i.e. `[['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1']]`
2. Build your permutations. Use `itertools.product`, see [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists)
3. From each of your permutations, you might want to create several, within a loop. E.g., from `('a1','b1','c1')` get `('a1','b1','c1')` and `('a1','b1')`. That is easy.

You can fill in the gaps.

**Build all and filter out**

... Probably only useful if you need something (slightly) different from what I understood.

Comment: Great!! That's excatly what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I've understood correctly your question, but do you mean this?

```
from itertools import permutations

my_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1']

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(list(permutations(my_list, i)))
```