# Generating a new list containing all combinations of a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I want something that was asked in [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists),
but using ONLY `while` or/and `for` loops. In the other words, without the use of `itertools` nor recursion.

I know many similar questions have been asked before, but unfortunately I could not find a desired answer. I have looked for some solutions which make use of both loops and recursions, but when I attempted to translate them into only loops, I found out it did not work for me. I have thought of putting `for` loop inside a `while` loop but then it works differently than using recursion, because the entire `for` loop finishes before another `while` loop starts.

I have stuck for hours, any help/hint is greatly appreciated. I am using Python 3 though!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are asking for an implementation of `itertools.product` using only for-loops, you'll find exactly that in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: Assuming that args is always <listof <listof Str>>, is there any way to change this so neither tuple nor yield is used?

Comment: @slopys1324 Well, sure. Use `list` instead of `tuple`, and accumulate the results of the last for-loop into a list and return it instead of using yield.

Comment: Probably the last question. Is there an equivalent way of doing `[x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]` instead of putting two for-loops on one line? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried myself but it ends up with an infinite loop for some reason.