# unique combinations values in a dictionary

Tags: python

For the following example dictionary, is there a builtin method to get all unique combinations?

```
a = {
  "a": ["a_1", "a_2"],
  "b": ["b_1", "b_2"]
}
```

output:

```
[
  ["a_1", "b_1"], 
  ["a_1", "b_2"], 
  ["a_2", "b_1"], 
  ["a_2", "b_2"]
]
```

Comment: Thats straightforward with `itertools`... does it have to be built-in?

Comment: May be `list(itertools.product(*a.values()))` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2):

I did this with `itertools.product()`

```
import itertools
a = {
  "a": ["a_1", "a_2"],
  "b": ["b_1", "b_2"]
}
print(list(itertools.product(*a.values())))
```

Output:

```
[('a_1', 'b_1'), ('a_1', 'b_2'), ('a_2', 'b_1'), ('a_2', 'b_2')]
```