# How to create unique combinations from specific fields in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create all combinations of items from four fields in my dataframe.  I'm testing the code below, and something is wrong because I keep getting 'out of memory' errors.

```
import itertools
A = df['ID']
B = df['PRICE']
C = df['YIELD']
D = df['SCORE']
a = [A, B, C, D]

data = list(itertools.product(*a))
idx = ['c{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(data)+1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=list('abc')).T

df
```

I have 10,000 rows of data in this example.  In other dataframes there will be many more rows.  Is this possible, or is the resulting object just too large?

Comment: `((Number of columns)^2)*(Number of rows)` will be the number of rows you will get at the end.

Comment: In the case of this 10000 row example, `len(data)` = 10000^4

Comment: You might try [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists)