# How to get every string variations with list of possibilities for each position

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have a list of lists called `master_list`, which has the following properties:

1. Each list inside the `master_list` contains strings that are single digit positive integers
2. Each list inside the `master_list` has a length from 2 to 5
3. The `master_list` has a length from 1 to 8

What I want to do is return a list of string variations using the list of posibilities for each position.

Here is an example of a `master_list` and what the output would look like:

```py
master_list = [['3', '2', '6'], ['6', '5', '3', '9'], ['9', '8', '6']]

#  In this case the output would contain 3*4*3 = 36 elements 

output = ["339","366","399","658","636","258","268","669","668","266","369","398",
           "256","296","259","368","638","396","238","356","659","639","666","359",
           "336","299","338","696","269","358","656","698","699","298","236","239"]
```

Comment: Have you tired something?

Comment: I've tried iterating through each list with nested for loops, then I realized that I would need to use recursion because the number of lists is variable. But I'm stuck on how to do that.  The nested loops got me the output above but its essentially hard coded for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 've tried iterating through each list with nested for loops, then I realized that I would need to use recursion because the number of lists is variable. But I'm stuck on how to do that. The nested loops got me the output above but its essentially hard coded for that case.

Try this (It uses [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)):

```
import itertools

li = [['3', '2', '6'], ['6', '5', '3', '9'], ['9', '8', '6']]
result = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(*li)]
print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
['369', '368', '366', '359', '358', '356', '339', '338', '336', '399', '398', '396', '269', '268', '266', '259', '258', '256', '239', '238', '236', '299', '298', '296', '669', '668', '666', '659', '658', '656', '639', '638', '636', '699', '698', '696']
```

If you want to convert each element into `int`:

```
result = [int(''.join(i)) for i in itertools.product(*li)]
```

Answer (score 1):

itertools product will give you all combinations in tuples
as in this example 
[All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists) 
then you can concat each tuple to a single string, or create a number and convert to string