# Python - Permutation of list of list (Not all same size)

Tags: python

Hello here is what I want to do

```
ListToPerm = [[1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2]]

Ouput
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,2,1]
...
[2,3,2]
```

I can't seem to find anything that does this. Any answer does not do this desired output.

Comment: [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on G.Anderson's comment that you'll want `itertools.product`:

```py
from itertools import product

l = [[1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2]]

list(product(*l))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2)]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, just missed the * in the previous attempts at using itertools.