# How to get all combinations of list elements in python?

Tags: python

Assume that we have n lists in python like `A1,A2,...,An.` We name `A*={x1,x2,...,xn}` a combination of these lists if `x1` is in `A1, x2 is in A2,..., xn` is in `An`. By mathematics, we know that the number of these combinations is `|A1| * |A2|*... * |An|`. How can I code a function in python to do this for me and return all these combinations?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists

Comment: I am afraid this may be duplicate: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

a1 = range(0, 3)
a2 = range(3, 6)
a3 = range(6, 9)

print(list(product(a1, a2, a3)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 3, 6), (0, 3, 7), (0, 3, 8), (0, 4, 6), (0, 4, 7), (0, 4, 8), (0, 5, 6), (0, 5, 7), (0, 5, 8), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8)]
```