# Python: combine tuples

Tags: python, tuples, combinations

I have `m`-length list of tuples.
For example:

```
m = 2
mylist = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

I need to get all combinations of these tuples, using only one element from one tuple:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
```

For `m=3`:

```
mylist = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]

[1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 6]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 6]
```

Is there any good way to do it for any `m`?

Comment: You can probably use some combination of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) and [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) or the like. But I'm not sure I 100% understand your requirements. You said "one element from one tuple", but you used two elements from one tuple.

Comment: @kojiro, I mean in each combination I can use only one element from each tuple, for example I can't do `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Can you add an example where the first element of the resulting pairs comes from a tuple that is not the _first_ tuple in `my_list`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists) - `list(itertools.product(*my_list))`

Comment: `itertools.product` is probably what you're looking for

Comment: @Tomerikoo, It does, thank you a lot!

Comment: Great, so mark it as a duplicate or delete the question. And try to do some research before asking. I'm only saying that for your own benefit. I can only imagine the time and effort it took you to write this question. This could all be saved by simply Googling `python all combinations of a list of tuples`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```py
import itertools

for el in itertools.product(*mylist):
    print(el)
```

Outputs:

```py
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
```

Ref. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product