# All conditional permutations of a nested list in python

Tags: python, math, permutation

I have an array like bellow (A) and I want to convert it to (B).

**A**:

```py
A = [['a', 'ae', 'oa'], ['a'], ['l'], ['y', 'i']]
```

**B**:

```py
B = ['aaly',
'aali',
'aealy',
'aeali',
'oaaly',
'oaali']
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
from itertools import product

A = [['a', 'ae', 'oa'], ['a'], ['l'], ['y', 'i']]

res = ["".join(p) for p in product(*A)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['aaly', 'aali', 'aealy', 'aeali', 'oaaly', 'oaali']
```

As an alternative use:

```
res = list(map("".join, product(*A)))
```