# How to create all possible combinations of parameters in a dictionaryP

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

I have the following dictionary:

```
hyper_params = {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'], 'class_weight': [None, 'balanced'], 'max_iter': [500, 1000]}
```

I need to train `LogisticRegression` of `sklearn` on all possible combinations of parameters from `hyper_params`, e.g.:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', class_weight=None, max_iter=500)
LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', class_weight=None, max_iter=500)
etc.
```

How can I create all possible combinations of these 3 parameters, so that I can pass them as `**args_comination` to `LogisticRegression`.

I cannot use the hyperparameters optimisation library. Therefore I'm searching for a custom approach to enumerate `hyper_params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists) you can achieve this by `itertools.product()`. So:

```
import itertools

hyper_params = {
    'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
    'max_iter': [500, 1000]
}


a = hyper_params.values()
combinations = list(itertools.product(*a))

for c in combinations:
    LogisticRegression(penalty=c[0], class_weight=c[1], max_iter=c[2])
```

Or if those are positional arguments in your `LogisticRegression` function you can even do:

```
for c in combinations:
    LogisticRegression(*c)
```

Comment: Sure, I was waiting when the acceptance button becomes available (there is a minimum waiting time threshold in stackoverflow).

Comment: Huh, didn't know that :) Cheers!