# How to do a nested loop over a variable length list of generators?

Tags: python, generator, combinations, variable-length, nested-for-loop

I have a list of generators `L = [gen_1,...,gen_n]` with variable length `n`.

How can I implement in a compact way the following:

```
for el_1 in gen_1:
    for ...
        for el_n in gen_n:
            do_something([el_1,...,el_n])
```

That should be a fairly common problem, but somehow I can't figure it out and also could not find anything online so far.

Unlike in the simpler case of iterating over the Cartesian product over a list of generators [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/how-to-get-the-cartesian-product-of-multiple-lists), a variable-depth for loops allows to execute code at any level.

As an example problem, maybe we can assume the simple case of tracking the index of each loop's generator:

```
i_1 = 0
for el_1 in gen_1:
    i_1 += 1
    i_2 = 0
    for ...
        i_n = 0
        for el_n in gen_n:
            i_n += 1
            do_something([el_1,...,el_n],[i_1,...,i_n])
```

This is just an example of calling some code in a specific place in the nested for loop. Specific being bound by the length of the list of the generators.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Maybe this question is closer to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/q/798854/2932052

Comment: That is a great help already. But I think your answer is incomplete and if my question was not asked like this before, closing it is not the right approach.

Comment: For example, imagine the theoretical for loop. How would you exactly call any code in a certain level of the nested for loop when iterating over the product? For example keeping track of the index of each loop.

Comment: You can use `enumerate` to get the index along with the item of an iterator

Comment: I actually can answer this question now, only that it is unfortunately closed...