# PHP string split and combine

Tags: php, string, yii, split

I have a string: "This is a [boy/girl] in a [house/car]
I want split it into 4 strings:

1. This is a boy in a house
2. This is a girl in a house
3. This is a boy in a car
4. This is a girl in a car

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any PHP code in your question.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "permutations". You'd need a loop or recursive function after preferrably regex-matching the alternatives in square brackets.

Comment: See also [Need algorithm to make simple program (sentence permutations)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5613089) for the approach. (There's also a PHP example somewhere.. Use the search if you just came for copy+pasting.)

Comment: I want a solution for this. not code. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
$string = 'This is a [boy/girl] in a [house/car]';
preg_match_all('/\[(.+?)\]/', $string, $matches);
$find_array = $matches[0];
foreach($matches[1] as $row) {
    $replace_array[] = explode("/", $row);
}

$output[] = str_replace($find_array,array($replace_array[0][0],$replace_array[1][0]),$string);
$output[] = str_replace($find_array,array($replace_array[0][1],$replace_array[1][0]),$string);
$output[] = str_replace($find_array,array($replace_array[0][0],$replace_array[1][1]),$string);
$output[] = str_replace($find_array,array($replace_array[0][1],$replace_array[1][1]),$string);

print_r($output);
```

//output

> ```
> [0] => This is a boy in a house
> [1] => This is a girl in a house
> [2] => This is a boy in a car
> [3] => This is a girl in a car
> ```

Comment: thank you very very much.
I'm looking for global case so I need loops but I don't know how many step for loop. (sorry for my English)