# Is there any way to use NUnit TestCaseAttribute with ValuesAttribute together?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am using intensively NUnit `TestCase` attribute. For some of my tests are annotated with 20+ `TestCase` attributes defining 20+ test cases. However I would like to test all the 20 test cases say with an extra value what could be 1 or 0. This means for me *different* test cases. This easily could be implemented with `ValuesAttribute`:

My current state:

```
[TestCase(10, "Hello", false)] // 1
[TestCase(33, "Bye", true)]    // 2
// imagine 20+ testcase here)]
[TestCase(55, "CUL8R", true)]    // 20+
public void MyTest(int number, string text, bool result)
```

I would like to do something similar to this (what I can not:)

```
[TestCase(10, "Hello", false)] // 1
[TestCase(33, "Bye", true)]    // 2
// imagine 20+ testcase here)]
[TestCase(55, "CUL8R", true)]    // 20+
public void MyTest([Values(0,1)] int anyName, int number, string text, bool result)
```

Why I would like to do this? Because these 40+ combination means different test cases.  Unfortunately NUnit does not allow using [`TestCase`] and [`Values`] attributes together, the test runner expects *exactly* the same number of parameters as it listed in `TestCaseAttribute`. (I can understand the architect, but still...)
The only thing I could figure out was this:

```
[TestCase(1, 10, "Hello", false] // 1
[TestCase(1, 33, "Bye", true]    // 2
// imagine 20+ testcase here]
[TestCase(1, 55, "CUL8R", true]  // 20

[TestCase(0, 10, "Hello", false] // 21
[TestCase(0, 33, "Bye", true]    // 22
// imagine 20+ testcase here]
[TestCase(0, 55, "CUL8R", true]  // 40
public void MyTest(int anyName, int number, string text, bool result)
```

So I ended up to be forced to commit the sin of the copy and paste, and I duplicated the TestCases, now I have 40+. There must be some way... What if not only (0,1) the range of the value but 0,1,2,3. We are ending with 80+ copied testcases?

Missed I something?

Thx in advance

Comment: Why don't add one more test case?

Comment: Adding one more test case for every existing test case means _duplicating_ the number of test cases. I have 20+ now I will have 40+.

Comment: It's not something I've got into myself, but would [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) help?

Comment: @ClickRick Yes, TestCaseSource may help, but then I have to write programmatically what I can describe with the two kind of attributes clearly and more shortly in _declarative_ way. Also using TestCaseSource the producing factory code will be in other location in the code, and will not resides clearly near the _testing_ code, which will decrease the code readability.

Comment: Then I can only suggest asking on the [NUnit discussion forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nunit-discuss) as the `TestCaseSourceAttribute` was designed with exactly your case in mind. I don't see how having one non-duplicated set of test cases listed is less clear than duplicating the list, with all the inherent problems which that brings; nor do I see how it has to be far from the testing code. You do, however, so your case would seem to be more specialised than had been envisaged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This came up as a first page search result for me despite its age, but I wanted something lighter than the existing solution.

Using another `ValuesAttribute` or `ValueSourceAttribute` for the test cases allows combinations, but the trick is to get a set of linked values as a single case when using them - each affects only a single named parameter.

Attributes require compile-time constant inputs. That allows you to make a literal array, but if your values are of different types, you'll have to make the array a common base type, like `object`. You'll also have to access the items by index. I like short, obvious unit tests; parsing the array makes the test look busy and messy.

One terse solution is to use a `ValueSource` attribute with a static method providing tuples. This method can immediately precede the test method, and is only a little more verbose than using the `TestCase` attribute. Using the code from the question:

```
public static (int, string, bool)[] Mytest_TestCases()
{
    return new[] {
        (10, "Hello", false),
        (33, "Bye", true),
        (55, "CUL8R", true)
    };
}

[Test]
public void Mytest(
    [Values(0,1)] int anyName,
    [ValueSource(nameof(Mytest_TestCases))] (int number, string text, bool result) testCase)
```

The parameter following the `ValueSource` is a tuple named `testCase`, and its contents are named to match the original test case arguments. To reference those values in the test, precede it with the name of the tuple (e.g. `testCase.result` instead of just `result`).

As written here, six tests will run - one for each possible combination of `anyName` and `testCase`.

I don't mind tuples for simple data like in this example, but I went a little further and defined a very simple class to use in place of the tuples. Usage is basically the same, except you don't name the members within the parameter.

```
public class Mytest_TestCase
{
    public Mytest_TestCase(int number, string text, bool result)
    {
        Number = number;
        Text = text;
        Result = result;
    }
    public int Number;
    public string Text;
    public bool Result;
}

public static Mytest_TestCase[] Mytest_TestCases()
{
    return new[] {
        new Mytest_TestCase(10, "Hello", false),
        new Mytest_TestCase(33, "Bye", true),
        new Mytest_TestCase(55, "CUL8R", true)
    };
}

[Test]
public void Mytest(
    [Values(0,1)] int anyName,
    [ValueSource(nameof(Mytest_TestCases))] Mytest_TestCase testCase)
```

The test case class definition could be moved to the bottom of the test class, or to a separate file. Personally, I prefer to put both at the bottom of the test class - you can always peek the definition when you want to see it next to the test.

Comment: Together with records and target type new it can be simplified to:
```
public record Mytest_TestCase(int number, string text, bool result);

        public static Mytest_TestCase[] Mytest_TestCases()
        {
            return new Mytest_TestCase[] {
                new(10, "Hello", false),
                new(33, "Bye", true),
                new(55, "CUL8R", true)
            };
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, The class that provides the test data is test code in its own right and is therefore first class code and should be maintained as such.

If you give the class a meaningful name I would contend it can be readable and maintainable, perhaps more so, as your test data is in one place.

This is how I would implement your case:

1. Make a class, we'll call it `TestCaseGenerator` that has `int`, `string` and `bool` attributes.  it would look like this:

   ```
    public class TestCaseGenerator : IEnumerable {

        #region Attributes
        internal static List<TestCase> TestCases { get; set; }
        internal int myInt { get; set; }
        internal string myString { get; set; }
        internal bool myBoolean { get; set; }

        #endregion

        static TestCaseGenerator() {
            var json = <jsonRepresentationOfMyTestData>
            TestCases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestCase>>(json);    
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
            return TestCases != null
                      ? TestCases.Select(x => new TestCase(x.myInt, x.myString, x.myBool) ?? "null")).GetEnumerator()
                      : null;
        }
     }
   ```
2. Construct the class containing your tests like this:

   ```
    public class MyTestClass {
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCaseGenerator))]
        public void MyTest(TestCase case) {
            // Do useful things with case.myInt, case.myString and case.myBool
        }
    }
   ```

Once you have this infrastructure in place there is nothing to say `TestCaseGenerator.GetEnumerator()` which returns an enumerator over a list of `TestCase` objects couldn't be written in a way to return a combined list of two shorter lists.

Creation of a combined enumerable (borrowing from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473575/combinations-of-multiple-list)) would look like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var firstArray = new object[][] { new object[] { 1, "A", false },
                                          new object[] { 2, "B", false },
                                          new object[] { 3, "C", false },
                                          new object[] { 4, "D", true },
                                          new object[] { 5, "E", true }
                                       };

        var secondArray = new object[] { 6, 7 };

        var joiner = new Joiner();
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> result = joiner.Join(firstArray.ToList(), secondArray.ToList());

        //result = new object[] { new object[] { 6, 1, "A", false },
        //                        new object[] { 7, 1, "A", false },
        //                        new object[] { 6, 2, "B", false },
        //                        new object[] { 7, 2, "B", false },
        //                        new object[] { 6, 3, "C", false },
        //                        new object[] { 7, 3, "C", false },
        //                        new object[] { 6, 4, "D", true },
        //                        new object[] { 7, 4, "D", true },
        //                        new object[] { 6, 5, "E", true },
        //                        new object[] { 7, 5, "E", true }
        //                      };
    }
}

public class Joiner
{
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> Join(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> source1, IEnumerable<object> source2) {
        foreach (IEnumerable<object> s1 in source1) {
            foreach (object s2 in source2) {
                yield return (new[] { s2 }).Concat(s1).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```