# How to find subsets with exact length using linq lambda syntax

Tags: c#, linq, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lists permutations (unknown number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286882/lists-permutations-unknown-number)

Lets say I have input of `Range[1, 8]`

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

and i want to find `Subsets[%, {2}]` (all subsets with exact length of 2)

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, 
 {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}, 
 {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 8}}
```

Tried:

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 8);
var result = from v in values
             from v2 in values.Skip(v)
             select new[] { v, v2 };
```

Comment: Have you checked MoreLINQ and EvenMoreLINQ?

Comment: LINQ and Lambda aren't necessarily the same thing.  You can build an extension method pretty easily that takes a lambda expression (though in this case, what would the expression look like?  Need more info) and then does the subset computations with a recursive function body.

Comment: Joel Etherton > Well i can call Mathematica with `"Subsets["+list+", {2}]"`. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Subsets.html

Comment: What you've tried gives me the exact results you're looking for.  What's the issue?

Comment: @user1793607 The OP has shown the *combinations* as his desired output, not *permutations*.  See wikipedia for the difference.

Comment: @Margus can you explain what's wrong with code you tried? It brings exactly what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function to find all combinations of an input sequence of a specified size:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();


    int count = 1;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        foreach (var innerSequence in source.Skip(count).Combinations(n - 1))
        {
            yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(innerSequence);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

So in your case you'd use it as:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 8).Combinations(2);
```

Comment: What a great snippet. However it took me a moment to get that it is missing a `public static class ExtensionMethods` wrapper.

Comment: @Servy did you any performance testing? Your method is about 30 times slower than other two methods! I get no clue why it is so.

Comment: @nawfal That wouldn't surprise me.  This method covers the general case, the other methods hard coded in many of the details, in particular the size of the result set.  Making that not fixed adds a lot of complexity to both the code, and inhibits many optimizations.  Now, that said, there are implementations of the general case that are more efficient, but they're also much harder to understand conceptually.  Finally, note that combinations scale horribly, even in the best case, so you won't be able to use this for large data sets regardless of the quality of your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from a in Enumerable.Range(1, 8)
            from b in Enumerable.Range(a + 1, 8 - a)
            select String.Format("{{{0}, {1}}}", a, b);

foreach (string s in query)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: This is a bit hacky though, as it doesn't work with any other input sizes or set sizes.

Comment: Can definitely be extended if needed. This answers the specific question asked.

Comment: It's actually non-trivial to extend it from a fixed number of items in the result set to a dynamic result set size.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lst = Enumerable.Range(1, 8);
var result = lst.Join(lst, c => 1, c => 1, (i, j) => new[] { i, j })
        .Where(c => c[0] < c[1]);
```

Here I used the condition `1 == 1` to get the cross join of values in `Enumerable.Range(1, 8)` to get all possible combinations.

As noted in comments probably an easier way to generate a cross join is by:

```
var result = lst.SelectMany(_ => lst, (i, j) => new[] { i, j })
        .Where(c => c[0] < c[1]);
```

but is less readable to my eyes.

Please note that this is little less efficient compared to other methods as this first gets all the possible combinations and then trim down the unwanted. Nevertheless a simple one-liner.

Comment: You can get a cross join through a simple `SelectMany` call with much less hassle.

Comment: @Servy I can not understand if that's what a SelectMany does from the documentation. Can you edit my answer and post it as an answer?

Comment: Edited as requested.  Also note that from an efficiency point of view it's probably better to just generate what you need, as the other posts do, rather than generating all permutations and trimming it down.

Comment: @Servy Yes I had noticed that.