# Generating a n-ary Cartesian product example

Tags: c#, .net, linq, cartesian-product

I found that Eric Lippert's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098381/720616) suits a particular problem I have.

The problem is I can't wrap my head around how I should be using it with a 2+ amount of collections.

Having

```
var collections = new List<List<MyType>>();
foreach(var item in somequery)
{
    collections.Add(
            new List<MyType> { new MyType { Id = 1} .. n }
        );
}
```

How do I apply the cartesian product linq query on the *collections* variabile ?

The extension method is this one:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>()};
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) => 
            from accseq in accumulator 
            from item in sequence 
            select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})                       
        );
 }
```

Here is Eric's example for 2 collections:

```
var arr1 = new[] {"a", "b", "c"};
var arr2 = new[] { 3, 2, 4 };
var result = from cpLine in CartesianProduct(
                     from count in arr2 select Enumerable.Range(1, count)) 
             select cpLine.Zip(arr1, (x1, x2) => x2 + x1);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lists permutations (unknown number)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286882/lists-permutations-unknown-number)

Comment: @EricLippert 's extension method is far more comprehensible (at least for me) and concise than any of the solutions in those possible duplicates..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample code is already able to do "n" cartesian products (it does 3 in the example).  Your problem is that you have a `List<List<MyType>>` when you need an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyType>>`

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyType>> result = collections
  .Select(list => list.AsEnumerable())
  .CartesianProduct();
```

Comment: no need to use AsEnumerable() as each List is already an IEnumerable, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327167/1819480

Comment: @Infinum not quite...  the CartesianProduct method takes an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`  If you don't call `AsEnumerable`, you have an `IEnumerable<List<T>>` which is not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Much like the original poster of this question, I also had a hard time wrapping my head around the usage of this awesome function. The main thing that caught me was that I had to create this single `IEnumerable` full of `IEnumerable` before calling the function (again just like the original post).

The way my code was set up was that I had 3 arrays with data in them that I needed to multiply together, and creating this greater `IEnumerable` was going out of my way, and I didn't want to do that.

So instead I re-wrote the function to extend off of `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` so now I can call the function directly off of any of the arrays that I want to multiply and just pass in the other 2 arrays as parameters. I thought I'd repost here incase anyone else was interested in using it this way:

> ```
>     public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>
>     (this IEnumerable<T> firstSequence, params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
>     {
>         IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
>
>         foreach (IEnumerable<T> sequence in (new[] { firstSequence }).Concat(sequences))
>         {
>             result = from resultItem in result 
>                      from sequenceItem in sequence 
>                      select resultItem.Concat(new[] { sequenceItem });
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

This would be an example of using this method on 3 arrays of data.

> ```
>         var numbers = new object[] { 1, 2, 3 };
>         var letters = new object[] { "a", "b", "c" };
>         var colors = new object[] { "red", "blue", "yellow" };
>
>         var result = numbers.CartesianProduct(letters, colors);
> ```

The output

> ```
>         [1, a, red]
>         [1, a, blue]
>         [1, a, yellow]
>         [1, b, red]
>         [1, b, blue]
>         [1, b, yellow]
>         [1, c, red]
>         [1, c, blue]
>         [1, c, yellow]
>         [2, a, red]
>         [2, a, blue]
>         [2, a, yellow]
>         [2, b, red]
>         [2, b, blue]
>         [2, b, yellow]
>         [2, c, red]
>         [2, c, blue]
>         [2, c, yellow]
>         [3, a, red]
>         [3, a, blue]
>         [3, a, yellow]
>         [3, b, red]
>         [3, b, blue]
>         [3, b, yellow]
>         [3, c, red]
>         [3, c, blue]
>         [3, c, yellow]
> ```

Comment: Hi @Blake, did you get any OutOfMemory exception when dealing with a large number of items in the sets while calculating CartesianProduct.

Answer (score 0):

Since `List<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>`, then your problem using Eric's solution is solved as follows:

```
var collections = new List<List<MyType>>();
var product =  collections.CartesianProduct();
foreach(var collection in product)
{
    // a single collection of MyType items
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        // each item of type MyType within a collection
        Console.Write(item);
    }    
}
```

Of course you can aggregate the items from each collection in a more concise manner, for example as a single `string`:

```
var product = 
    collections
    .CartesianProduct()
    .Select(xs => xs.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, x) => sb.Append(x.ToString()), sb => sb.ToString()));

foreach(var collectionAsString in product)
{
    Console.WriteLine(collectionAsString);
}
```