# Algorithm for generating variations based on different sets containing different values

Tags: algorithm

In short I am looking for a way in Java/C# for generation of all possible variations based on different sets containing different values. 
For example:
Lets say we have set of names:

```
 -Max, Jack, Roger
```

Second set of verbs

```
-Loves, hates, knows
```

And third set of programming languages just as an example but we may have 10 sets

```
-Java, C#, Python, Visual Basic, C++
```

What I want is a way to generate all possible variations containing ALL attributes and having all values for example an output should be :

```
Max loves Java
Jack loves Java
Roger loves Java
Max hates Java
Jack hates Java
Roger hates Java
Max knows Java
Jack knows Java
Roger knows Java
Max loves C#
Jack loves C# 
Roger loves C#
and so on... this will generate 45 variations if I am not wrong at the end
```

Can anyone help ?
I believe a similar easier example will be if you want to generate a variations of products in some clothing shop which have different sizes, colors and materials for example and you want all variations.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx and links seq.

Comment: Lots on SO when you search Cartesian Product; pick your favourite dupe :)

Comment: Simply loop through each set and append the strings? e.g, something like `for i in (Max, Jack, Roger) for j in (loves, hates) for k in (Java, C#) print i+j+k;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] names={"Max", "Jack", "Roger"};
String[] verbs={"Loves", "hates", "knows"};
String[] languages={"Java", "C#", "Python", "Visual Basic", "C++"};
for(String name:names)
   for(String verb:verbs)
      for(String language:languages)
         System.out.println(name+" "+verb+" "+language);
```

**EDIT:**

Oh ,i see . I misunderstood the question .
You can just use the magic of recursion to solve this.
This is what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] sets={
            {"Max", "Jack", "Roger"},
            {"Loves", "hates", "knows"},
            {"Java", "C#", "Python", "Visual Basic", "C++"},
    };
    combine(sets,0,"");
}

public static void combine(String[][] list,int index,String upperText)
{
    if(index==list.length)return;
    for(String i:list[index]){
        combine(list,index+1,upperText+i);
        if(index==list.length-1){
            System.out.println(upperText+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a bit more tricky sicne the amount of for loops was not fixed.. I mean the amount of "sets" is not just 3 and I didnt want repercussion ... but anyway I didnt asked correctly so thanks for tha snwer

Comment: Yup I agree with recursion you can :) I also found this answer which is in C# but shows good solution as well using the C# magic :)  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545703/combination-of-listlistint Anyway I've done it already with recursion :)