# Possible combinations

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list

I'm having a array of Lists

```
List<string>[] possibleLines;
```

Array can be of different size also each each List<> can have different number of strings. Fore example

- `List<string>[0]` - can have strings "first string", "second string"
- `List<string>[1]` - "third string", "fourth string", "fifth string"

I need to get all possible combinations, each string must be from different list (array size may differ). For example

- "first string", "fourth string"
- "first string", "fifth string"
- "second string", "fourth string"

and so on.

Comment: Can you post what code you have tried or where it failed?

Comment: And to clarify, you want **combinations** and not **permutations?**

Comment: Can the strings in the results be in a different order than the lists they came from (is ["fourth string", "first string"]) a valid result?) , and if so, are different orderings considered different results (should we include both ["first string", "fourth string"] and ["fourth string", "first string"])?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades That's only an option with a number of lists known at compile time.  Here it's not.

Comment: Possible solution is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545703/combination-of-listlistint

Comment: First string must be form first List, second string from second List and so on so "first", "fourth" correct, "fourth", "first" not correct

Comment: @Servy: Why?  It's a very rare day that I know how long my arrays are at compile time!

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Yes, I know that.  That's my point.  For nested loops to work, you need to know the number of lists at compile time because you need a loop per list.  Therefore, because the number of lists are *not* known at compile time, nested loops (at least, alone) is not a suitable means of solving the problem.

Comment: @Servy: No, sorry, it's perfectly simple to loop through the data and put together all unique combinations.  I slapped it together in six lines, it tests fine.  I'd post an answer, but I think the OP needs to show a little effort before handing it to him.  Perhaps I'm missing something in your objection?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Your solution isn't *just* nesting loops though; that's likely not even the "interesting" aspect of it.  There's likely a recursive call, or something else along those lines, that allows it to be dynamic, and *that* is likely to be the "interesting" part of the solution.  Generating combinations by just nesting loops is the solution *when the number of collections is known*.

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing here is computing the Cartesian Product of an unknown number of collections.  Eric Lippert describes how to write a solution to this problem in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) (which I *strongly* suggest you read to see how he comes up with this solution).

The code he ends up with as his result is:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

Comment: Love the article.  I read through it and needed to visualize what was going on. Added an answer that adds the visualizing code to this solution. +1 for the great article!

Comment: Thank you it seems what I want. But I don't how to use it, I mean retrieve those combinations. Could you show an example.

Comment: @user2412672 You call `CartesianProduct` on `possibleLines`, and it gives you a sequence of sequences, where each inner sequence represents one combination.  You can `foreach` the total result to do something for each combination, and then `foreach` each combination to print them out, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was a pretty cool math problem, but I wanted to visualize the actual process so I wrote this for anyone that wants to test out what Servy (well, Eric Lippert) wrote:

```
int length = 4;
var lists = new List<List<string>>();
var random = new Random(1234);

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{        
    var inLength = random.Next(4, 8);
    var tempList = new List<string();
    for (int j = 0; j < inLength; j++_
    {
        tempList.Add(string.Format("{{String Coords: {0}, {1}}}", i, j));
    }
    lists.Add(tempList);
}

var cp= lists.CartesianProduct();
var output = RenderString(cp);
```

and `RenderString`:

```
private static string RenderString(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> cp)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in cp)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(item.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This will give you an `output` that looks like

```
{String Coords: 0, 0}{String Coords: 1, 0}{String Coords: 2, 0}{String Coords: 3, 0}
{String Coords: 0, 0}{String Coords: 1, 0}{String Coords: 2, 0}{String Coords: 3, 1}
{String Coords: 0, 0}{String Coords: 1, 0}{String Coords: 2, 0}{String Coords: 3, 2}
{String Coords: 0, 0}{String Coords: 1, 0}{String Coords: 2, 0}{String Coords: 3, 3}
{String Coords: 0, 0}{String Coords: 1, 0}{String Coords: 2, 0}{String Coords: 3, 4}
{String Coords: 0, 0}{String Coords: 1, 0}{String Coords: 2, 1}{String Coords: 3, 0}
...
{String Coords: 0, 4}{String Coords: 1, 4}{String Coords: 2, 6}{String Coords: 3, 4}
```

Pretty cool if you want to visualize what is going on.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Aggregate` to build strings.  You end up creating lots of intermediate strings that aren't needed.  And the use of a SB is way more verbose than is needed.  Just use `string.Concat`.  `RenderString` can be implemented as `return string.Concat(cp.Select(s=>string.Concat(s)+"\n"));` and it'll be shorter, clearer, and pretty dramatically more efficient in both time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more procedural approach that is horrible to read, but is about twice as fast as Eric Lippert's suggestion.

```cs
static IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    var arrays = sequences.Select(s => s.ToArray()).ToArray();
    var numColumns = arrays.Length;

    if (numColumns == 0)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            Array.Empty<T>()
        };
    }

    var arrayLengths = arrays.Select(l => l.Length).ToArray();

    var arrayIndices = new int[numColumns];
    var numRows = arrayLengths.Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);

    var lastColumnIndex = numColumns - 1;

    var combinations = new IReadOnlyList<T>[numRows];

    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        var items = new T[numColumns];
        for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numColumns; columnIndex++)
        {
            items[columnIndex] = arrays[columnIndex][arrayIndices[columnIndex]];
        }
        combinations[rowIndex] = items;

        for (var i = lastColumnIndex; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var updatedIndex = arrayIndices[i] = (arrayIndices[i] + 1) % arrayLengths[i];
            if (updatedIndex > 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return combinations;
}
```