# How can I concat the elements from multiple lists/arrays to form one list with all the unique values from the original lists?

Tags: c#, list

I should state that this is not a permutation issue and that I would like to do this in C#. I have a variable number of lists of strings and each list has a variable number of elements.

So for example:

List 1:
One
Two

List 2:
Uno
Dos
Tres

List 3:
1
2
3
4

The results should end up being:
OneUno1
OneUno2
OneUno3
OneUno4
OneDos1
OneDos2
OneDos3
OneDos4
OneTres1
OneTres2
OneTres3
OneTres4
TwoUno1
TwoUno2
TwoUno3
TwoUno4
TwoDos1
TwoDos2
TwoDos3
TwoDos4
TwoTres1
TwoTres2
TwoTres3
TwoTres4

The real issue here is that the final list can get very large very fast so I run into problems if I do this in memory, so my thought is to write the strings out to a file as I generate them but I'm having issues trying to figure out the logic/algorithm for doing this.

Comment: What's your purpose of generating so many elements that it doesn't fit in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example](https://ideone.com/xmk25N):

```
    var list1 = new[]{"One", "Two"};
    var list2 = new[]{"Uno", "Dos", "Tres"};
    var list3 = new[]{1,2,3,4};

    var result = from a in list1
         from b in list2
         from c in list3
         select new {a, b, c};

    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.a + " " + item.b + " " + item.c); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer on this but how would you handle a variable number of lists in this scenario?

Comment: @DanScott0806 look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545703/combination-of-listlistint

Comment: Yep that would be exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is simple *cross* `Join`.

```
IEnumerable<string> results = from l1 in list1
    from l2 in list2
    from l3 in list3
    select string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", l1, l2, l3);
```

I'm not quite sure how large output in your case, if it is really large and *want* to write it to file in chunks you could do this.

Note previous Linq statement returns only `IEnumerable<string>` .

```
foreach(var smallchunk in results.Take(1000))
{
     System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("filepath", smallChunk); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer on this but how would you handle a variable number of lists in this scenario?