# How to create single dimensional, two dimensional,three dimensional as well as multi dimensional array using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

I am trying to keep all the combinations (5C1, 5C2, 5C3, 5C4, 5C5) of 1,2,3,4,5 into individual array. So I need to create dynamic array using for loop in c#.

Say for example,
Here n = 5 and r = 1 to 5. 
if r = 1 then
My array will be single dimensional array, when r = 2 then it will be two dimensional array, when r = 3 then three dimensional, when r = 4 then four dimensional array and it will e continued up to end of 5.
My code is given below

```
string[] ShipArrayObj;
  public frmResult( string[] ShipArray )
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        ShipArrayObj = ShipArray;
    }

    private void frmResult_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arr = ShipArrayObj;           
        int n = ShipArrayObj.Count();
        for (int r = 1; r <= n; r++)
        {                
            StoreCombination(arr, n, r);
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "/";                
        }

    }

    void StoreCombination(string[] arr, int n, int r)
    {           
        string[] data = new string[r];            
        createCombination (arr, data, 0, n - 1, 0, r);
    }


   private void createCombination(string[] arr, string[] data, int start, int end, int index, int r)
    {
        if (index == r)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < r; j++)
             richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + data[j].ToString();//Where I want to set array to keep combination values
             return;
        }

        int i = 0;
        for (i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= r - index; i++)
        {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            CreateCombination(arr, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r);
        }
    }
```

I am storing all the combination into a Rich Text Box, but want to keep into array. If anybody help me then I will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to something like Java then multidimensional arrays are a little different in syntax in C#.

[Here's a page describing how to do them in C#.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)  Here's a snippet from said page:

```
// Two-dimensional array.
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
// The same array with dimensions specified.
int[,] array2Da = new int[4, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
// A similar array with string elements.
string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" },
                                        { "five", "six" } };

// Three-dimensional array.
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                 { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
// The same array with dimensions specified.
int[, ,] array3Da = new int[2, 2, 3] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                       { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

[If you're interested in different combinations of things with a fixed number of them, something like this should be all you need.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545722/569302)

[If you're interested in different combinations of things with a dynamic number of them, something like this should be all you need.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545740/569302)

(Unless you're trying to optimize performance, it's better to be readable/expressive, generally speaking.)

You may need to consider whether or not order matters (un-ordered set vs. ordered list).   I would assume it doesn't from your code (in which case sorting is good to eliminate "duplicates"), but I can't tell for sure.

---

Here's a good example that's easy to read and modify for variations and isn't so bad for small numbers:

```
// -1, 0, ..., 5
var choices = Enumerable.Range(-1, 6); 

var possibleChoices = 
    from a in choices
    from b in choices
    from c in choices
    from d in choices
    from e in choices
    select (IEnumerable<int>)new [] { a, b, c, d, e };

// Remove -1's because they represent not being in the choice.
possibleChoices =
    possibleChoices.Select(c => c.Where(d => d >= 0));

// Remove choices that have non-unique digits.
possibleChoices =
    possibleChoices.Where(c => c.Distinct().Count() == c.Count());

// Sort the choices to indicate order doesn't matter
possibleChoices =
    possibleChoices.Select(c => c.OrderBy(d => d));

// Remove duplicates
possibleChoices = 
    possibleChoices.Select(c => new 
                           {
                               Key = string.Join(",", c),
                               Choice = c
                           }).
    GroupBy(c => c.Key).
    Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault().Choice);

foreach (var choice in possibleChoices) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", choice));
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 3
2, 4
3, 4
0, 1, 2
0, 1, 3
0, 1, 4
0, 2, 3
0, 2, 4
0, 3, 4
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 4
1, 3, 4
2, 3, 4
0, 1, 2, 3
0, 1, 2, 4
0, 1, 3, 4
0, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

---

This is probably a little more dense to understand, hard-coded to this specific variation of combination and involves recursion but is a bit more generic/isn't hard-coded to `5` (and took `0.047s` on dotnetfiddle.net instead of `0.094s`).  It's also completely lazy/`IEnumerable`.

```
public static void Main()
{       
    var possibleChoices = Choose(5);

    foreach (var choice in possibleChoices) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", choice));
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Choose(int max) 
{       
    var remaining = Enumerable.Range(0, max); 

    return ChooseRecursive(remaining, Enumerable.Empty<int>());
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> ChooseRecursive(IEnumerable<int> remaining, IEnumerable<int> chosen) 
{       
    yield return chosen;

    foreach (var digit in remaining) 
    {
        var choices = ChooseRecursive(
            remaining.Where(d => d > digit), 
            chosen.Concat(new [] { digit })
        );
        foreach (var choice in choices)
        {                   
            yield return choice;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
0, 1
0, 1, 2
0, 1, 2, 3
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
0, 1, 2, 4
0, 1, 3
0, 1, 3, 4
0, 1, 4
0, 2
0, 2, 3
0, 2, 3, 4
0, 2, 4
0, 3
0, 3, 4
0, 4
1
1, 2
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 4
1, 3
1, 3, 4
1, 4
2
2, 3
2, 3, 4
2, 4
3
3, 4
4
```

Comment: Your given output is OK. From this list I want to choose random line of values by using loop or other ways so that I can use those values into an operation. If you can please give a way, How can I keep those value into an array or list? @WLJ

Comment: @PritamJyotiRay Call ToArray() on the IEnumerable and then choose one at a random index.  If you need to do this more than once, cache the ToArray call for each unique integer.  If you want to cycle through then create a data structure that shuffles and then returns each item successively until it goes through each, in which case it re-shuffles.  Ask a new question if you'd like an implementation :)